# Unity parameter initialization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I started to learn Unity recently.
I have a question after a tutorial.

Here is a audio parament need to be initialized.
`1. AudioSource attackSound;
    ...
 2. AudioSource[] audios = GetComponents<AudioSource>(); 
 3. attackSound = audios [0];`

I don't understand the meaning of 2 & 3, Can someone help me or the doucument is fine too.
Sorry for my English and first time to use C# ( learned C & JAVA already)

Comment: This initialization is also available in Java, so if you have already learnt Java, it shouldn't be a problem. It also isn't a specific syntax for Unity.

Comment: You should take the time to learn c# before attempting to learn Unity. For line 2, what you are looking for is Generics

Comment: sorry ,actually not learn JAVA completely Cause the school project I dont have enough time .I'll go to find this thx

Comment: [`GetComponents`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html) returns **array** of `AudioSource` and stores it in the `audios` . For `attackSound = audios [0];`, the first element in the `audios` array is accessed and then used to initialize the `attackSound` variable. It seems like you don't understand arrays. I suggest you do what Camilo suggested to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Line 2, `GetComponents<AudioSource>();` is what's called a generic method. Between the `<>` you can specify any type you want, provided it is in the constraints of whatever the method says.

`GetComponent<>` and `GetComponents<>` have a constraint that whatever type you pass, has to inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. This can be shown in the example:

```
var x = GetComponent<int>();          // Won't work. Int does not inherit from MonoBehavior
var y = GetComponent<AudioSource>();  // Works. AudioSource from MonoBehaviour.
```

`GetComponents` will return an array, which is a set amount of variables of the same type grouped together, paired with an index used to get that element. For example:

```
// Creating the string array. This contains three string variables "A", "B", and "C"
string[] strings = new string[] 
{
    "A", "B", "C"
};

Console.WriteLine(strings[0]);    // Returns the first element,  in this case "A"
Console.WriteLine(strings[1]);    // Returns the second element, in this case "B"
Console.WriteLine(strings[2]);    // Returns the third element,  in this case "C"
```

You notice, arrays count from 0, not from one, so to get the nth element, you must use `[n - 1]` or you'll get an `OutOfRangeException`.

So Line 3 is getting the first element that is being returned from `GetComponents<AudioSource>();`.

All that being said, arrays are Day 1 C# and generics follow soon after. I spent months studying C# before I even touched Unity. Just because Unity is the current goal, doesn't mean you can skip the necessary steps.

Go into Visual Studio, do small practice projects, watch YouTube tutorials or get Jon Skeet's C# In Depth First Edition. When you're comfortable with C#, *then* you can move onto Unity. Gotta learn one thing at time, and walk before you can run.

Comment: okay,i got it. Very appreciate for you guys such detailed description and suggestion. I'm trying to get balance on my work, cause changing my major in college. You're right. Walk before you can run. I should not be hasty. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome! It'll be much easier learning them separately, and hopefully it'll still be fun. If this helped, then by sure to upvote it and mark it as the correct answer by hitting the checkmark next to my answer, please (:

Comment: Okay,but I can vote only cause having less than 15 reputation :O

Comment: Oh well what can you do xD